# Why is my JLabel icon causing a NullPointerException error when it is a default generated code from importing image and suggestions to fix?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

Being new to NetBeans, I am following the steps shown here to add an image to a JLabel: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html

Before anyone tries to point me to other threads, I have looked through a lot of them. Many people talk about not having the image in the correct location and such, but would such a problem crop up with the way I'm doing it, since I am literally importing the image directly to the package?

I have looked through it multiple times and my image is most definitely in the folder. I've also tried people suggesting taking off the first backslash from the path, doesn't work.

Below is the file system of my project in NetBeans:

```
Source Packages
|_ com.mycompany.hangmangame
|    |_ Screen.java
|_ com.mycompany.hangmangame.images
     |_ FailStamp.png
```

The default generated code is:

```
// logo is the name of my JLabel
logo.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/mycompany/hangmangame/images/FailStamp.png"))); // NOI18N
```

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
    at com.mycompany.hangmangame.Screen.initComponents(Screen.java:89)
    at com.mycompany.hangmangame.Screen.<init>(Screen.java:24)
    at com.mycompany.hangmangame.Screen$1.run(Screen.java:156)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: I don;t use Netbeans but I would check if it is copying the image to the binary folder structure (`bin/com/...`, `build/com/...` or whatever the project is set to - there where the `*.class` files are) - you can try `System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/com/mycompany/hangmangame"))` to see where the `images` folder is being expcected.  (the path `images/FailStamp.png` should also work)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thank you so much! That helped me fix it, the tutorial I referred to had the package end up in the um...where the .java file was, not the .class files!

Comment: no problem, little hint: check the return from `getResouce` and, if `null`, show/print an error message (including name and path)